# How do I reset the lost password of a Pi 4 running Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, password, cmdline.txt

I would like to reset the password of my raspberry pi 4 4gb running Ubuntu server 20.04, most tutorials involve adding `init=/bin/sh` to cmdline.txt, however when I do this I get a kernel panic.

Roughly along the lines of:

`/bin/sh: splash: No such file or directory`

`Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!…`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would put the sd card into another machine, mount the disk and edit the file `/etc/shadow` to remove the password; delete the characters between the first and second colons in the file. Save the file and eject the sd card.  The user will no longer have a password and you can boot the pi log in and set one up.

Comment: has the right answer, but isn't `/bin/sh` supposed to go last? This sounds like you put it before `splash`.

Answer (score 2):

Mount it on another rpi(or any linux box with `qemu-user-static` installed).
`mount --bind` the /dev /sys and /proc directories.
`chroot` into it.

References:
https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation
https://wiki.debian.org/chroot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).